# LED of the F4 key is always on

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a Lenovo T14 gen1 with AMD Ryzen 7.

I installed ubuntu 20.10 (in dual boot with windows) but the F4 key (mute microphone) is always on with Ubuntu (but works fine with Windows)

Is there a way to turn this LED off if microphone is off and turn it on if microphone is on ?

Comment: It's quite likely driven by specific software/firmware/drivers supplied by Lenovo & equally likely that's only available for Windows.

Comment: That key works fine here (Windows 10, X1 Carbon).  Can you get a better Linux audio driver?

Comment: I edited my post : it works fine on windows but not on ubuntu.

Comment: That further supports my guess.